# Error opening downloaded file from server

Tags: php, file, download, server

I want user to click and download a .doc to wherever they want.. The files download but when you open it, Word says: 'Missing File C:\Users\MyName\style.css. I click OK and then it shows me a corrupted word document.

PHP

```
<?php
function download($pathToFile) {
header('Content-description: File Download');
header('Content-type: application/force-download');
header('Content-transfer-encoding: binary');
header('Content-length: '.filesize($pathToFile));
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($pathToFile).'"');
readfile($pathToFile);
}

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['CVcrono'])){
            download('../curriculum-vitae-modelo1-azul.doc');
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['CVfun'])){
            download('../curriculum-vitae-modelo1b-azul.doc');
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['CVcomb'])){
            download('../curriculum-vitae-modelo1c-azul.doc');
        }
    }
?>
```

HTML

```
<tr>
        <td>
            <input class='entButton' type='submit' name='CVcrono' value="Descargar">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='entButton' type='submit' name='CVfun' value="Descargar">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='entButton' type='submit' name='CVcomb' value="Descargar">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try insert

```
ob_clean();
ob_flush();
flush();
```

before

```
readfile($pathToFile);
```

Comment: flush cleans buffer PHP.
ob_clean clears if suddenly you before reading the file appears HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the header to:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
```